# cat on big files does not work

Tags: shell, cat, compression

I'm trying to concatenate four big files in two. The files *_1P.gz contain the same amount of lines as the corrisponding *_2P.gz.

The files `A_1P.gz` and `A_2P.gz` both contain `1104507560` lines.
The files `B_1P.gz` and `B_2P.gz` both contain `1182136972` lines.

However, `cat A_1P.gz B_1P.gz > C_1P.gz| wc -l` returns `186974687` lines, and `cat A_2P.gz B_2P.gz > C_2P.gz| wc -l` returns `182952523` lines, so both are not only way smaller than the two input files (they should be more than 2B lines long and they're less than 2M instead), but also they have a different number of lines. The command ran showing no errors whatsoever.

I can't understand what's happening, I generated those four big files with `cat` as well and it worked properly.

- What could the problem be?
- What other options do I have to concatenate gzipped files without using `cat`?

I'm working on a CentOS server. I still have 197G space, so that shouldn't be an issue (or it should show an error, at least).

Comment: When you're counting _lines_, don't you want to count the uncompressed lines? Also the pipeline `cat file1 file2 >file3 | wc -l` does not make sense as `wc` would get _no_ data. What's the command that you are actually using?

Comment: What command(s) did you use to count the lines in the original files?  It's possible that you unintentionally used some wrapper that silently decompressed them first.  Try showing the size in bytes (using `wc -c`) instead of lines.

Comment: @Kusalananda I obtained the line count of the four big files doing `zcat *P.gz | wc -l`. The actual command was `cat file1 file2 > file3; wc -l file3`, but actually I didn't precede it with `zcat`, and that might be the root of my problem. If that's so, I'll feel really stupid...

Comment: @LinuxBlanket yes, you need to count the uncompressed lines, since lines are defined by `\n` and there is no reason to expect to have a specific number of `\n` characters in the compressed file.

Comment: Obviously a cat eating big files is not an healthy diet. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that the files are *compressed*.  You can't therefore use `wc -l` on the files directly to count the original number of lines in them without decompressing them first.

It's OK to use `cat` for concatenating these types of compressed files as the resulting file is a valid compressed file in itself. Uncompressing it later would result in a file that is the concatenation of the uncompressed data from the two files.

```
cat A_1P.gz B_1P.gz >C_1P.gz
```

To count the number of lines in `C_1P.gz`:

```
zcat C_1P.gz | wc -l
```

or

```
gunzip -c C_1P.gz | wc -l
```

or

```
gzip -dc C_1P.gz | wc -l
```

but note that we need to uncompress the file to count the lines, otherwise we'll be counting the "random" newlines that the file compression algorithm generates as part of the compressed data (these have nothing to do with the lines in your uncompressed file).

Comment: ...yes, I realized thanks to your comment that, unlike for `A_1P.gz` and `B_1P.gz` line count, I didn't uncompress the file before counting lines, and doing `zcat file | wc -l` yielded the correct line number. I'm sorry for the silly question, I don't know how I didn't see it before...

Comment: @LinuxBlanket It's an easy mistake to make.